# How can I make my tags go to a new line whenever they go outside the div django-taggit

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-models

So for starters I am using django-taggit for a tagging system on my site. Everything was going well until I decided to try really long strings and many of them. It turns out it spills out of the div. I would like to know how can I make it go to a new line in the div whenever this happens, or even to limit the max characters allowed for each tag/limit the amount of tags allowed.

Here is the relevant models.py

```py
    class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images',blank=True,null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='post_files',blank=True,null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,auto_now_add=True)
    comments_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    NSFW = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

And here is the relevant HTML file

```html
{% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <li class="tag-list-box"><a class="tag-list-style" href="{% url 'mainapp:tagged' tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        {% empty %}
        <li>No tags</li>
        {% endfor %}
```

EDIT: Here is the CSS

```css
.tag-list-box {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

So how would I go about breaking a line when the tags start spilling out of the div or even how to limit the actual number of allowed tags

Comment: This is a css question.  Show you css for `tag-list-box`

Comment: Ok I added the CSS code

Comment: Going to need more - this isn't specifying the sizing

Comment: Try out white-space: word-break; in your CSS